# Nginx and Chrome error Waiting for available sockets

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, sockets, nginx, tcp

I have a problem with my Nginx. If I serve my page and files with node, everything is working ok but if I use Nginx, after I refresh my site quickly a few times I get stalled request and message 'Waiting for available sockets'.
The problem is with ssl_socket_pool and max connection of 6 that Chrome gives us. How do I close those connections when they are done. How should I setup my nginx and why is there no problem when not using Nginx?

This is my Nginx config

```
daemon off;

worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

# max number of opened files

worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;

events {
  # optmized to serve many clients with each thread

    use epoll;

  # if accept_mutex is enabled, worker processes will accept new connections by 
    turn. Otherwise, all worker processes will be notified about new connections, 
    and if volume of new connections is low, some of the worker processes may 
    just waste system resources.

    accept_mutex on;

  # accept as many connections as possible, may flood worker connections if set 
    too low -- for testing environment

    multi_accept    on;

  # determines how much clients will be served per worker

    worker_connections 1024;
}

# error logs

error_log   logs/nginx/error.log;

http {

    charset utf-8;

    # Include default mime.types that were generated automatically

    include mime.types;

    # add extra mime types

    types {
        application/x-httpd-php .html;
    }

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log     off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';

    access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;


    # # - Basic Settings

    # copies data between one FD and other from within the kernel
    # faster then read() + write()

    sendfile        on;

    # send headers in one peace, its better then sending them one by one

    tcp_nopush      on;

    # don't buffer data sent, good for small data bursts in real time

    tcp_nodelay       on;

    types_hash_max_size       2048;

    # # - Enable open file cache

    # nginx can cache static files for a short period of time. Adding this within your configuration block tells nginx to cache 1000 files for 30 seconds, excluding any files that haven’t been accessed in 20 seconds, and only files that have been accessed at least 2 times in that timeframe. However, it also means that the server won't react immediately to changes on disk, which may be undesirable

    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid   30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses    2;
    open_file_cache_errors  on;


    # # - Security

    # limit the number of connections per single IP

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;

    # limit the number of requests for a given session. This creates a shared memory zone called "login" to store a log of IP addresses that access the rate limited URL(s). 10 MB (10m) will give us enough space to store a history of 160k requests. It will only allow 1 request per second (1r/s).

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;


    # # - Configure buffer sizes

    # this is used to handle POST data, meaning form submissions, file uploads etc. Make sure that the buffer is large enough if you handle a lot of large POST data submissions

    client_body_buffer_size 16k;

  # Sets buffer size for reading client request header. For most requests, a buffer of 1K bytes is enough.

    client_header_buffer_size   1k;


    # # - Responds with 413 http status ie. request entity too large error if this value exceeds

  # directive assigns the maximum accepted body size of client request, indicated by the line Content-Length in the header of request.

    client_max_body_size    8m;

    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;


    # # - Configure Timeouts

    # allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    # Defines a timeout for reading client request body. The timeout is set only for a period between two successive read operations, not for the transmission of the whole request body.

    client_body_timeout 10;

    # Defines a timeout for reading client request header. If a client does not transmit the entire header within this time, the 408 (Request Time-out) error is returned to the client.

    client_header_timeout   10;

    # use a higher keepalive timeout to reduce the need for repeated handshake. Timeout during which a keep-alive client connection will stay open on the server side. The zero value disables keep-alive client connections.

    keepalive_timeout   15;

    # maximum number of requests that can be served through one keep-alive connection. After the maximum number of requests are made, the connection is closed.

    keepalive_requests 100;

    # established not on the entire transfer of answer, but only between two operations of reading; if after this time client will take nothing, then Nginx is shutting down the connection.

    send_timeout    10;

    # # - Hide nginx version information

    # isables emitting nginx version on error pages and in the “Server” response header field (for security)

    server_tokens   off;

    # # - Dynamic gzip compression

  gzip                      on;
    gzip_http_version         1.1;
    gzip_disable              "msie6";
    gzip_vary                 on;
    gzip_min_length           20;
    gzip_buffers              4 16k;
    gzip_comp_level           4;
    gzip_proxied              any;


    # Turn on gzip for all content types that should benefit from it.

    gzip_types  application/ecmascript;
    gzip_types  application/javascript;
    gzip_types  application/json;
    gzip_types  application/pdf;
    gzip_types  application/postscript;
    gzip_types  application/x-javascript;
    gzip_types  image/svg+xml;
    gzip_types  text/css;
    gzip_types  text/csv;
    gzip_types  text/javascript;
    gzip_types  text/plain;
    gzip_types  text/xml;
    gzip_types  text/json;

    # proxying requests to other servers

    upstream nodebeats {
      server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    keepalive   32;
  }

    server {
      listen       <%= ENV['PORT'] %>;
      server_name  _;
      root        "/app/";

      limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 5;
      limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=10 nodelay;

      location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|png|ico|json|xml|svg)$ {
        root                 "/app/src/dist/";
        add_header         Pragma public;
        add_header         Cache-Control public;
        expires            1y;
        gzip_static        on;
        gzip               off;
        log_not_found      off;
        access_log         off;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header     Connection "";
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass         http://nodebeats;
        add_header         Cache-Control no-cache;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you check your nginx access or error log?

Comment: Hi Yu-Lin. Sorry, I don't know where to get the logs. I am using nginx buildpack and doploying application to Heroku. I know I have access and error logs set in configuration but that is because most of configuration is copied from somewhere else.

Comment: You can get your nginx config file by `sudo service nginx -t`, and then cat the config file content to see what is `access_log` or `err_log` addressed.

Comment: sorry, I tried something but couldn't do it. Don't really know how to. I also accesed all of heroku files and couldn find anything related to nginx. Don't knw where to look when there are multi buildpacks. Will try again in morning. But I am pretty sure that the problem is the one that I wrote in my opening post. Because if I go to chrome://net-internals/#sockets adn flush socket pool it works again fast until it fills up again.